# Use Scrapy to extract info from multiple items from the item list on a page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, extract

Is it possible to use Scrapy to extract some data from all records of data from data list, so for every link from list view page, it opens link(details page), pick wanted information, return to list view, pick first item(link) beneath, do the same job for all items and for all pages(so for example 100 pages, every page has 10 records).
i.e, if I choose page [image]

i have multiple items list, crawler needs to go inside every item, open details view
[image]

scrape needed info, then get back to page 1 (from first attachment), go to another link and repeat the job for every item from every page. I know Scrapy can easily scrape needed data from first page, so for example price and title for all items, but is it possible to open that item, scrape some info which is visible in details page, come back and do it again for others?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to, given a list of item, open the details of an item, extract them, go back to the list, and repeat for the remaining items.

This is possible, but usually you don’t need to worry about coming back to the list. Instead, this is what you do (example, non-working code):

```py
def parse_list(self, response):
    for item_selector in response.css('.item'):
        item = item_data_from_selector(item_selector)
        yield response.follow(
            item['details_url'],
            callback=self.parse_item_details,
            cb_kwargs={'item': item})

def parse_item_details(self, response, item):
    item_details = parse_item_details(response)
    item.update(item_details)
    yield item
```

For each item you extract all data you can from the list, and yield a request (`response.follow`, which is an altearnative to `scrapy.Request`) for each item, pointed at their details URL, which includes the item data you have collected from the list. In the callback (`parse_item_details`) that parses the item details URL, you update the item data from the list with the additional details from the details URL, and you yield the complete item.

You don’t “go back to the list” at any moment. If you need to fetch the next page from the list, you do that from `parse_list` at the end, yielding a request for the next page, but you are never “going back” to a page. When you reach a page, you yield all the requests and items that you can from that page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the scrapy documentation/tutorials give you a pretty good idea how to do this. And I'm sure there are plenty of resources here and online that go even further. What have you tried so far?